# MySQL with Node.JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

Okay I found the error. For some reason it was a problem with my web server. I tried it on my other one and set up the mysql database on there. :)

I'm working on a Node.js server with socket.io and wanted to integrate some mysql connection. I installed the mysql module a bunch of times and it still doesn't work. I don't know why. 
Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    users = {};

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'host',
      user     : 'user',
      password : 'secret',
      database : 'db'
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('login', function (data, callback) {

        console.log(data);

        connection.connect(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log('test');
        });

        var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('result: ', result);
        });

        //Add user to array

        connection.end();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        //remove user from array
    });

});
```

It doesn't log anything when I connect :/

Thank you very much :)
Anton

Answer (score 1):

Because node.js is asynchronous, your call to `connection.end()` is being executed before the query. Try removing that line and see if it works

Comment: thanks but this didn't really fix the problem :/ could it be that my password or something is wrong? But wouldn't he throw me an error then?

Comment: @user3207681 If you suspect that is the case, `connection.connect()` accepts a callback `function(err) { }` you can check for any errors with connecting there

Comment: I've implemented it and updated my code. Ive also logged the data and its logging it, but theres no log in the connect block. not even the test log that I've put in there...

Comment: I've now deleted my server host and database and just put in localhost to see if it makes a difference, and now its showing me an error. but as soon as i enter my real information of the server its not even throwing an error. (I know those work, since I use them using PHP).